# Extract substring from xcom string in airflow 2.3.4 is returning unknown chararcter t

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have  a use case wherein I need to extract the last 2 values of a string returned from xcom_pull.

Version of Airflow : `2.3.4`

The value of `fy` is `2022` but I wanted only the last 2 digits i.e. `22`
Since the return type from xcom is string I used slicing but it does not seem to work.
Rather it return  `t`(space before t )

```
fy = "{{ ti.xcom_pull(dag_id='" + DAG_ID + "', task_ids='fiscal_yr_week')[1][3] }}"
xcom_yr = f"""{fy}"""
yr = xcom_yr[2:4]
```

[image]

Can someone let me know what is the glitch here ?

Answer (score 0):

You must set `render_template_as_native_obj` to `true` at your DAG definition so you will get result as a dict, not as a str

Then you can get any value you want
`fy = "{{ ti.xcom_pull(dag_id='" + DAG_ID + "', task_ids='fiscal_yr_week')}}["xcom_yr"]"`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The problem here is not in extracting the xcom value. I am getting correct value of ```fy``` . But I wanted to get the substring from teh string value of xcom. AT present fy  value  is this ```2022``` . What I want is  to extract only the last two digits so that the value will ```22```. 
```xcom_yr``` is the variable I have created  by fetching the ```fy``` value